# ReCAPTCHA auto submit, without submit button

Tags: recaptcha

I'm sorry, I speak a little English.

My secret content:

```
<p>Címek</p><ul id="secret"><li>Cím1</li><li>Cím2</li><li>Cím3</li></ul>
```

I would like see this (if can: without jQuery):

[image]

After valid reCAPTCHA, see (not use submit button):

[image]

I do not want use submit button.

How to?

Comment: Are you rendering the recaptcha currently?

Comment: Dear Adam, No, these pictures are just examples.

Comment: Is this just an HTML file?  Or are you using a framework like Spring?